# Typescript generic mapped type preserving key-value pairing

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I'm writing a library which allows the user to process some kind of object. The object may have a string `type` property defined, and I'd like to be able to extend the library with plugins that further process objects with a specific type. Let's illustrate with some code:

```js
type Entry = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

type TypedEntry<T extends string> = Entry & {
  type: T;
};

type PluginDefinition<T extends string = any> = {
  type: T;
  process(entry: TypedEntry<T>): void;
};

class Library {
  private plugins: Record<string, PluginDefinition> = {};

  registerPlugin(plugin: PluginDefinition): void {
    this.plugins[plugin.type] = plugin;
  }

  getPlugin<T extends string>(type: T): PluginDefinition<T> {
    return this.plugins[type];
  }
}
```

So far it works, but it's not optimal - for example this is not an error:

```js
this.plugins['foo'] = {
  type: 'bar',
  process(entry) {},
};
```

Also the only reason that the `getPlugin` method isn't throwing errors is that it sees `this.plugins[whatever]` as `PluginDefinition<any>`, which satisfies `PluginDefinition<T>`.

Both of these issues stem from the fact that I can't rewrite `this.plugins` as a mapped type, because there is no known list of types at this stage and therefore nothing to map over. But in theory neither of these two issues cares particularly about what the *actual* types will be, just that the key fits the `type` property of the value.

Is there any way to rewrite the `Record<string, PluginDefinition>` &co. so that these two issues disappear into the void, or perhaps to the never? I'm equally happy with either.

Comment: First one doesn't look like a real issue because `this.plugins` is encapsulated and can't be accessed out of `Library`. Could you clarify what's the second issue? `library.getPlugin('foo')` is `PluginDefinition<"foo">`

Comment: Well it seems like an issue to me, the type system isn't there only to sit between the library code and the rest of the world, but also to help protect the library code from internal bugs. I like being quite strict in my typings, so this rankles. `library.getPlugin('foo')` works, but the whole method could be dispensed with if just `this.plugins['foo']` worked as it was supposed to.

Comment: You can't type dynamic item that will be added at runtime and there's no generics for indexed property, so `this.plugins['foo']` can't work